# Is there something like banned.h for python?

Tags: python

I would like to be able to know if I am using any known bad modules in python. For c++ projects, I've used banned.h to determine if any of my includes are bad. I was hoping there's something similar for python, or something that looks through your project for bad modules.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you just want to turn on deprecation warnings when running your code (or test suite)?  They are ignored by default.

See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html